# App shows splash screen and then closes

Tags: ios, swift, button, crash, uibutton

The app had been working fine up until i tried to make the UIButton lead to a new view controller. At first, when i clicked the button it just closed the app.  But now the app opens in the simulator, but only shows the splash screen before closing and showing me the AppDelegate.swift file, which doesn't appear to have anything wrong with it.

Comment: Did you delete the button ? Update your viewController code

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean project as well as build folder using (select product & press option button), *clean* will change to *clean build folder*.